# How to replace string in lua?

Tags: string, replace, lua

My question is how can I replace the character from a given string?
If someone says something in the chat, and that word is a bad word then replace it with "****".
I don't know how to approach the print section.. Because I've got the index of the badword but I don't know how to replace it from the original message.

```
local badwords = {
    "badword",
    "badword2",
}

function(msg)
   local message = msg;
   local lowered_msg = message:lower(); 

   for index, val in pairs(badwords) do 
       if lowered_msg:match(val) then
           local indexStart, indexEnd = string.find(lowered_msg, val)
           print(message:gsub(indexStart, "*****", indexEnd))
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub` function takes three arguments:

- the string to be modified,
- the pattern to be replaced,
- and the replacement string,

so you need to do something like this:

```
message = string.gsub(message, message:sub(indexStart, indexEnd), "*****")
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Way use a table with badwords and replacements for gsub.

```
local badwords = {fair='f**r', foul='f**l'}
print(('fair is foul and foul is fair'):gsub('%w+', badwords))
```

...if the pattern matches words.
gsub() loops over the whole string except the 4th argument is used
[image]